# extract specific <div> classes from html to webview

Tags: android

So I'm developing this android app to piggy-back off of a school web page and retrieve specific 's within the html document. The problem is, when I use webview in android, I'm only allowed the whole page. Can anyone help me with understanding how to get specific parts of the html page? For instance, from the webpage included in my code below, I have this small bit of text from the

```
<div class="content"></div>
```

which I would like to be the only thing which shows up on the webview. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint; 
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public class accounts_activity_id extends Activity{


private WebView webView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.accounts_activity_id_main);
    Initialize();
}

private void Initialize(){

    WebView mainWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

    WebSettings webSettings = mainWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    mainWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyCustomWebViewClient());
    mainWebView.loadUrl("http://www.depauw.edu/it/onecard/");

    mainWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
}

private class MyCustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl("http://www.depauw.edu/it/onecard/");
        return true;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you are going at this the wrong way. Instead of opening the webpage directly in the WebView you should download the webpage and extract the relevant information and then show that in the WebView. This is usually called scraping.

You can do this either by manually download the webpage with an HttpURLConnection in Android or just use one of the many Java libraries (e.g. [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/)) that can do most of the work for you.

Comment: Once you have downloaded the page, you can use any HTML/DOM parser to get the data you need.